# Everytime I install yarn I get error Usage Error: The nearest package directory

Tags: installation, hadoop-yarn

I have try to install yarn  then this  happens  (Usage Error: The nearest package directory,

I have remove the yarn lock file   but got the same result

Then I checked the file path  to see,  if the pack json file was in the correct directory , and run the yarn command , however same issue came up.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove any `package.json` or `yarn.lock` in you workspace. For example i did have `package.json` in my root directory like so :

[my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkzi0.png)

Then just run `yarn install` in your project directory as usual..